# Обновление данных приложения

Tags: java, android, сокет, rest

Я написал Restful API на GO и мобильное приложение на Java. И каждый раз когда заходишь в приложение, обновляются данные (GET запросами). И чтобы увидеть изменения данных, нужно выйти из приложения и заново зайти. Подскажите мне пожалуйста, как не выходя из приложения обновить данные не используя технологии работающие в реальном времени (websocket), чтобы получилось красиво? Пожалуйста не судите строго, если мой вопрос неправильный. Я новичок в этом деле. Спасибо

Comment: Получается вы запрашиваете новые данные только при открытии приложения? Тогда вам нужно периодически в фоне проверять - имеются ли обновления на сервере, если есть - получаем и обновляем данные. Или сделайте обновление по действию пользователя (кнопки, свайпы и тд)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Andrey Mihalev!